# Map moving emplace with lvalue

Tags: c++, c++11, copy, move, std-pair

I am not sure if I understand correctly this code:

```
template<typename M>
void add(M& m,int i, std::string s)
{
  m.emplace(i,std::move(s));
}

int main()
{
  std::map<int,std::string> m;
  add(m,1,"foo");
}
```

When `add` is called, the `std::string` and the `int` are copied. The method `emplace` construct a `std::pair` which is moved into the `std::map` (no copy needed ). But the copy of `int` is a lvalue while the copy of `std::string` is cast to a rvalue, therefore which constructor is called to construct the `std::pair`? Since one argument cannot be moved, I suppose that an additional copy take place here. Is it right? Obviously, if I cast also the copy of `int` to a rvalue, I would expect no additional copies.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This constructor is called:

```
template< class U1, class U2 >
pair( U1&& x, U2&& y );
```

In this case `x` and `y` are not rvalue references but universal references. Long short story short, an lvalue (in this case the `int`) collapses to an lvalue reference and an rvalue (in this case the `std::string`) to an rvalue reference because of your `std::move()`.

The instantiated constructor looks like this:

```
pair( int& x, std::string&& y );
```

Scott Meyers explains it much better https://isocpp.org/blog/2012/11/universal-references-in-c11-scott-meyers

Comment: So the `std::pair` is constructed copying the `int` and moving the `std::string` right?

Answer (score 0):

> When `add` is called, the `std::string` and the `int` are copied.

The `int` is copied, but there's no initial `std::string` to copy. Instead, `s` is constructed in-place in the function itself from the string literal that you are passing in.

> therefore which constructor is called to construct the `std::pair`

We can mix and match. There's a forwarding-reference constructor template for [`std::pair`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/pair/pair):

> ```
> template< class U1, class U2 >
> pair( U1&& x, U2&& y );           // since C++11, until C++14
>
> template< class U1, class U2 >
> constexpr pair( U1&& x, U2&& y ); // since C++14
> ```

So in this case, we're calling `pair<int&, std::string>`. There is no "additional copy".